# jQuery sortable - div collaspes when attempt to sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list that the user can add to and delete from - the list can be any size in length.

I am attempting to add the [jQuery sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) to the list. The list should only allow the Customized Details to be sorted. The Customized Details will display in orange, when the user hovers over them.

However, when I attempt to drag/sort the Customized Details, the list collapses to a zero height, making the sort impossible.

I have been working on this issue for several hours now, tried many things, searched SO & Google - all failed.

**How can I display the sortable list, when the list height is dynamic and still complete the sort?**

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6233114/2d1hjym4/) of the issue I have.

Here is the relevant HTML code that the height issue may be issue (the rest of the code is in the JSFiddle):

```
<div class="live_preview_contents_display1" style="background: teal; overflow: auto;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2d1hjym4/2/) where the `ul` with class `sortable` does not have a `div` as child. That was why `sortable` did not work.

Comment: Thanks your solution works. The reason it did not work for me is because the list details are added dynamically with javascript, so I do have to figure out how to apply your solution to my js code.

Comment: You don't have to change much, just add `#live_preview` before `ul#sortableResumeDetails` as a wrapping div